# angular filter alphabetically but add new to top

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of objects coming to my page and I'm using orderBy:

```
orderBy:"name":false
// the object also has an id:number
```

this is great for the original list, but when I add new items, I want the items to go above the older items (until the page is refreshed). Is there a way to tell angular to automatically take care of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does not have a built in parameter to place new items at the top or bottom, but you could easily build the functionality in yourself. Upon creating an item, add a property like `item.isNew` Finally change your sort to a multisort:

```
orderBy:["isNew","name"]
```

This should have the desired result, and (combining with ng-class or css selectors) allows you to style the new item differently if you wish.

Edit:

Here is an [example jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/dopmb5q6/) I forgot to mention that the new items will be at the top, but all new items will be sorted by name. If you just want them just "pushed onto the stack" with no additional sorting change your "isNew" variable from a Boolean to an decrementing Integer ([example here](https://jsfiddle.net/c5pL9w1h/)).

Comment: Could he not just use the .$apply or tell angular to watch this item so that when it's added, the filter is applied??

Comment: The problem (as far as I understand) is not that the items are not added, or not sorted. The problem is that he wants new items on top. If there was a problem with the digest cycle because he was inserting items from outside of angular-land, the $apply could help, but I see no indication of that.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad It's not a critique, I am asking a question of Jonathan as an alternative.

Comment: @EvanBechtol I see, excuse my comment :)

Comment: @JonathanGawrych one question for you, where do I apply the 'false' part of the orderBy? does each sort property get its own?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad The false part is an optional parameter to reverse the sort order. If my memory serves me correctly, you can explicitly set it to false, or just omit that to sort *ascending*. If you wanted, for example, to sort *descending* on name, you can add a minus sign in front of the parameter (i.e. ```"-name"```)

Comment: @JonathanGawrych don't mean to bother you, but one more question. Would this work if I used the "id" as the second sort parameter (or first one)? Because I'm trying that before trying the "isNew" since I already have an "id" property

Comment: No bother! You could use a property like ```id``` instead of ```isNew```. However, if both your new objects and your old objects have an id, then your new objects will not show up on top. Instead they would be sorted with the rest of the items (unless the new items don't have an id, then that could work!). Multilevel sort works with an arbitrary number of parameters to sort on. Experiment to find the best system that works for you!